# values sent through jquery not being submitted in table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I've been trying to understand what is wrong ... but i am still clueless. Any help will be appreciated.

Following code inserts a form element

```
<?php foreach ($coal_type as $coal) {?>
<div class="checkbox">                                                    
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="usage_checkbox[]"  class="usage_checkbox" 
         value="<?php echo $coal['coal_type_id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $coal['coal_type']; ?>
    </label>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

This data is sent to a form handler which executes following code

```
obj_params.usage_checkbox = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='usage_checkbox[]']:checked").val();
```

This data is sent to the controller ( i am using codigniter) which inserts it

```
$i = 0;
 foreach ($this->input->post('usage_checkbox') as $key) {
      $coal_type[$i] = $key;
      $i++;
 }
 $coal_type[$i] = $this->input->post('other_usage');
 $c_type = implode(',', $coal_type);
 $arr_to_insert = array('type_of_coal' => $c_type,);
 $insert_id = $this->common_model->insertRow($arr_to_insert,'ekyc_details');
```

Now when i submit no value is inserted. I have tried everything but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: print `usage_checkbox` in console.it have any value or not?

Comment: I think you need to update your model code as well. You are trying to insert batch if I am not wrong.

Comment: i am using submit handler of jquery validator plugin which redirects the page back , it chekced for the console , not its not showing any value. thanks for reply.

Comment: also i am inserting other values of the form which are inseritng just fine... problem persists just with the checkbox values

Answer (score 0):

Here multiple values are get from the the checkbox.So you need to serialize to send the values through jquery.The following code will help you.

```
obj_params.usage_checkbox = $("input[name='usage_checkbox[]']:checked").serialize();
```